1969 NorCal Home - Foundation Settling vs. Foundation Problems: Advice Needed!
Thanks in advance for any advice or opinions! I'm in the process of considering a home purchase in Northern California (built in 1969, concrete perimeter foundation), and I’ve noticed some cracking that has me a bit concerned. I’ve browsed the sub for similar issues but wanted to get your thoughts on whether this looks like typical settling or something more serious.
Main areas of concern:
Front Window/Foundation: There's a noticeable step-pattern crack near the front window on the brick from the outside. And on the interior I noticed some building on a diagnal crack. I’ve read that the step type of crack could indicate an underlying foundation issue, and I’m wondering if this might be worrisome.
Back of the House (above Sunroom): There’s a horizontal-ish crack above the sunroom (see video). I know horizontal cracks can sometimes indicate pressure issues, so I wanted to get your thoughts on whether this needs immediate attention.
I've attached pictures here
Details about the house:
Location: Northern California
Year Built: 1969
Foundation: Concrete Perimeter
Roof: Composition
All windows and doors open and close without any issue.
Questions:
Does this look like standard settling, or should I be concerned about a more significant foundation issue?
Should I bring in a structural engineer or foundation specialist to inspect it further?
Has anyone dealt with something similar, and what were your experiences?

Get the structural engineer... Local would be a good idea. Other people's experiences are based on their local conditions - likely not the same...

Well, considering it's Cali—definitely local, because that engineer should be familiar with seismic design.
